# How to do logging in React Native

Tags: logging, react-native

How can I log a variable in React Native, like using `console.log` when developing for web?

Comment: Try out [react-native-log-ios](https://github.com/Annihil/react-native-log-ios) npm pkg, it works out of the box without remote JS debugging.

Comment: are you using RN to create a webb app ?

Answer (score 425, accepted):

`console.log` works.

By default on iOS, it logs to the debug pane inside Xcode.

From the iOS simulator, press (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and press **Remote JS Debugging**. This will open a resource, http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui on localhost. From there, use the Chrome Developer tools JavaScript console to view `console.log`

**Edit 2023**

You can just do `console.log` and it will print to the terminal you're running `react-native` in without any special commands

Comment: And how to print console log in Android using atom for React Native?

Comment: @sandy See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45833930/7219360). It's not specifically for Atom, but can be used in non XCode (aka non macOS) development

Comment: Note that as of React Native 0.29 and later, you can get logs without running the debugger. Just run react-native log-ios or react-native log-android on the command line inside your project folder.

Comment: And when you open the Remote JS Debugging, you have to press option+command+i and check the console. Totally necessary info that was missing and had me confused.

Comment: unfortunately its hard to work with error objects on this, console.dir wont print out the entire error object in this case

Comment: just remember console.log in production version of your app may crash your app in ios. so make sure you check if the environment is development you can know it by __DEV__ global variable in react native.

Comment: The `console` API seems to work without any import, so, having `import console from 'console';` in your file should result in `console.log is not a function` error.

Comment: I'm testing on an android device, run from my terminal without android studio, how can I log then?

Comment: I think you need to upgrade your react-native to the latest version, in my case that allows me to show console without enabling js debug trough **ctrl+m** in windows

Comment: What is the menu option for (⌘+D)? In my case, I press that combination and don't see anything happening. Assuming there is a Simulator option I have relatively misconfigured.

Comment: Excellent, how do you read the log in production?...

Comment: you can still use console.log with React Native when using metro, the console.log message will print out in the metro terminal

Answer (score 432):

Use `console.log`, `console.warn`, etc.

As of React Native 0.29, you can simply run the following to see logs in the console:

```
react-native log-ios
react-native log-android
```

Comment: This is very helpful since starting the debugger up makes animations slooooow.

Comment: This is not working. I get this messge when I run `react-native log-ios` **evelopers-Mac-mini com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.02C1B6C7-2CD2-406E-AC93-DD430E5E3C69[948] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd) <Notice>: Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.**

Comment: @rptwsthi I have the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Ben I open it today and it worked fine as it were. Did nothing just launched terminal, excuted `react-native run-ios` opened new tab and then ran `react-native log-ios` (Inside project directory of-course).

Comment: @Denis Kniazhev I don't think there's an option to only log errors, but you can filter the output. If you're on Mac or Linux: react-native log-android | grep "my filter for errors".

Comment: Using Remote JS Debugging as mentioned by @Yinfeng will give you just the logs without output, if you're looking for cleaner logging.

Comment: console.warn helped me to check certain concerns.

Comment: Does not work for me, I only see generic React Native log messages, such as `Initializing React Xplat Bridge.`.

Comment: Those logging commands don't work at all. They only log fatal exceptions. Anything that you print with `console.log` will not show up.

Comment: log-ios results in ```error No active iOS device found``` even though I'm seeing other logs show up via the Console.app

Answer (score 58):

Pre React Native 0.29, run this in the console:

`adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Post React Native 0.29, run:

`react-native log-ios`

or

`react-native log-android`

As Martin said in another answer.

This shows all console.log(), errors, notes, etc. and causes zero slow down.

Comment: +1 for this simple option. I ended up using a slightly variant command (after I Read The Fine Manual) to get timings also: `adb logcat -v time -s ReactNativeJS`

Comment: Keeping debug tab in background produces lag. The solution is to keep the tab in foreground or opening it in a new window.

Comment: I've been using React Native Debugger for months and it's the best option to avoid the lag Sabbir told: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Comment: `react-native log-android`
error Unrecognized command "log-android".
`react-native --version`
4.14.0

`adb logcat` continues to work with or without react-native tools installed.

Answer (score 52):

Use `console.debug("text");`

You will see the logs inside the terminal.

Steps:

- Run the application:

```sh
react-native run-ios        # For iOS
react-native run-android    # For Android
```

- Run the logger:

```sh
react-native log-ios        # For iOS
react-native log-android    # For Android
```

Comment: any way to filter only from console.log?

Comment: Does not work for me, I only see generic React Native log messages, such as `Initializing React Xplat Bridge.`.

Answer (score 28):

This is where **Chrome Developer Tools** are your friend.

The following steps should get you to the Chrome Developer Tools, where you will be able to see your `console.log` statements.

### Steps

1. Install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html), if you have not already
2. Run app using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`
3. Open developer menu

   - Mac: `⌘+D`  for iOS or `⌘M` for Android iOS
   - Windows/Linux: Shake Android phone
4. Select `Debug JS Remotely`
5. This should launch the debugger in Chrome
6. In Chrome: `Tools -> More Tools -> Developer Options` and make sure you are on the `console` tab

Now whenever a `console.log` statement is executed, it should appear in Chrome Dev Tools. The official documentation is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools).

Comment: This may slow down the performance of the app during development.

Answer (score 25):

Visual Studio Code has a decent debug console that can show your *console.log* file.

[image]

Visual Studio Code is, more often than not, React Native friendly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how VS Code can receive debug output from react-native. Thanks!

Comment: Select 'Debug JS' from your app on the device, and 'Toggle debug console(shift-command-y)' from your view menu on VS Code. You need https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native though.

Answer (score 24):

There are three methods that I use to debug when developing React Native applications:

1. `console.log()`: shows in the console
2. `console.warn()`: shows in the yellow box at the bottom of the application
3. `alert()`: shows as a prompt just like it does on the web

Answer (score 18):

Where you want to log data, use

```
console.log("data")
```

And to print this log in the terminal, use this command for Android:

```
npx react-native log-android
```

And for iOS:

```
npx react-native log-ios
```

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to recommend you guys using [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). You can download and install it by using this command ([Mac only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))).

```
brew update && brew cask install react-native-debugger
```

Comment: I'm using this instead the default `start`
This will open Debugger as you default debugger instead of Chrome and the `-g` flag will prevent it from hijacking focus on reloads.

`"start": "env REACT_DEBUGGER=\"$([ -d '/Applications/React Native Debugger.app' ] && echo \"open -g 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081' --args\")\" node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue: console messages were not appearing in Xcode's debug area. In my app I did <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to bring up the debug menu, and remembered I had set "Debug in Safari" on.

I turned this off, and *some* messages were printed to the output message, but not my console messages. However, one of the log messages said:

```
__DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON"
```

This was because I had previously bundled my project for testing on a real device with the command:

```
react-native bundle --minify
```

This bundled without "dev-mode" on. To allow development messages, include the `--dev` flag:

```
react-native bundle --dev
```

And console.log messages are back! If you aren't bundling for a real device, don't forget to re-point `jsCodeLocation` in `AppDelegate.m` to localhost (I did!).

Answer (score 4):

Press [command + control + Z] in Xcode Simulator, choose Debug JS Remotely, then press [command + option + J] to open Chrome developer tools.

[Xcode Simulator Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4mON.png)

refer：[Debugging React Native Apps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html)

Answer (score 4):

It's so simple to get logs in React-Native.

Use **console.log** and **console.warn**

```
console.log('character', parameter)

console.warn('character', parameter)
```

This log you can view in the browser console. If you want to check the device log or, say, a production APK log, you can use:

```
adb logcat

adb -d logcat
```

Comment: Everything shows up on ADB except for the `console.log` and `console.warn` statements.

Comment: Yes  @AndrewKoster I agree with you, we can view the all logs with ADB but this give you device logs here the query is related to logging a web development.

ADB gives you device logs as well you can control and check device configurations. 

You can gather information from bellow link of ADB commands which can help you while development.  
https://www.androidcentral.com/10-basic-terminal-commands-you-should-know

Answer (score 4):

There are two options to debug or get the output of your React Native application when using:

#### 1. The emulator or a real device

For first using the emulator, use:

```
react-native log-android
```

or

```
react-native log-ios
```

to get the log output

#### 2. On a real device, shake your device.

So the menu will come from where you select remote debug and it will open this screen in your browser.
So you can see your log output in the console tab.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are on OS X and using an emulator, you can view your `console.log`s directly in [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29)'s web inspector.

Safari → Development → Simulator - [your simulator version here] → JSContext

Answer (score 3):

The [react-native-xlog](https://github.com/EngsShi/react-native-xlog) module, that can help you, is [WeChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WeChat)'s [Xlog](https://github.com/Tencent/mars/) for React Native. That can output in the Xcode console and log file, and the Product log files can help you debug.

```
Xlog.verbose('tag', 'log');
Xlog.debug('tag', 'log');
Xlog.info('tag', 'log');
Xlog.warn('tag', 'log');
Xlog.error('tag', 'log');
Xlog.fatal('tag', 'log');
```

Answer (score 3):

Something that just came out about a month ago is "Create React Native App," an awesome boilerplate that allows you (with minimal effort) to show what your app looks like live on your mobile device (ANY with a camera) using the Expo app. It not only has live updates, but **it will allow you to see the console logs in your terminal just like when developing for the web**, rather than having to use the browser like we did with React Native before.

You would, of course, have to make a new project with that boilerplate... but if you need to migrate your files over, that shouldn't be a problem. Give it a shot.

*Edit: Actually it doesn't even require a camera. I said that for scanning a QR code, but you can also type out something to sync it up with your server, not just a QR code.*

Answer (score 3):

**Development Time Logging**

For development time logging, you can use ***console.log()***. 
One important thing, if you want to disable logging in production mode, then in Root Js file of app, just assign blank function like this - console.log = {}
It will disable whole log publishing throughout app altogether, which actually required in production mode as console.log consumes time.

---

**Run Time Logging**

In production mode, it is also required to see logs when real users are using your app in real time. This helps in understanding bugs, usage and unwanted cases. There are many 3rd party paid tools available in the market for this. One of them which I've used is by **[Logentries](http://logentries.com)**

The good thing is that Logentries has got **[React Native Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-logentries)** as well. So, it will take very less time for you to enable Run time logging with your mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the remote js debugly option from your device or you can simply use **react-native log-android** and **react-native log-ios** for iOS.

Comment: What is *"debugly"*?

Answer (score 2):

console.log() is the easy way to debug your code, but it needs to be used with the arrow function or bind() while displaying any state. You may find Stack Overflow question *[How can I print state in the console with React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500481/how-to-print-state-in-console-with-react-native)* useful.

Answer (score 2):

Every developer is facing this issue of debugging with React Native, and even I faced it too. I refer to this and the solution is sufficient for me at the initial level. It covers a few ways that help us to try and use whatever is comfortable with us.

1. Debugging with console.log
2. Debugging code (logic) with [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/)
3. Debugging code (logic) with Chrome
4. Use Xcode to debug GUI

https://codeburst.io/react-native-debugging-tools-3a24e4e40e4

Comment: *"[Retiring the Nuclide Open Source Project](https://nuclide.io/)"*

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use the React Native debugger for logging and [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)) store - https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Just download it and run as software. Then enable Debug mode from the simulator.

It supports other debugging features, just like element in Google Chrome developer tools, which helps to see the styling provided to any component.

Last complete support for Redux development tools.

Comment: The GitHub link is broken (404).

Comment: What do you mean by the last paragraph? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

1. Put `console.log("My log text")` in your code
2. go to your command line tools
3. position oneself in its development folder

In Android:

- write this command: `React-native log-android`

In iOS:

- write this command: `React-native log-ios`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron). It will give you a lot more functionality than just logging.

Comment: Highly recommend -- Reactotron gives you a console PLUS full visibility into your redux store PLUS a log of api calls, events, etc. I could not develop in React Native without it

Answer (score 2):

You use the same thing that is used for regular web. The `console` command also works in this case. For example, you can use `console.log()`, `console.warn()`, 
`console.clear()` etc.

You can use Chrome Developer to use the `console` command when you're logging while you are running your React Native app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VSCode and run your emulator with [VSCode React Native Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native), you can see `console.*` statements in the output tab. Make sure to select the correct subtab in the dropdown within the output tab. Mine currently is named *LogCat - emulator-5554*.

Answer (score 1):

**`console.log()`** is the best and simple way to see your log in the console when you use a remote JavaScript debugger from your developer menu.

Answer (score 1):

There are normally two scenarios where we need debugging.

1. When we are facing issues related to data and we want to check our data and debugging related to data. In that case,

   `console.log('data::', data)`

   and debug JavaScript remotely is the best option.
2. Another case is the UI and styles related issues where we need to check the styling of the component. In that case, react-dev-tools is the best option.

[Both of the methods are mentioned here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging).

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this by two methods**

1. by using warn

   ```
    console.warn("something " + this.state.Some_Sates_of_variables);
   ```
2. By using Alert. This is not good every time. If it reaches an alert then each time a popup will be opened, so if doing looping it means it is not preferable to use this.

   ```
    Import the {Alert} from 'react-native'

   // Use this alert
   Alert.alert("something " +this.state.Some_Sates_of_variables);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Users with Windows and Android Studio:

You're going to find it under Logcat in Android Studio. There are a lot of logging messages that show up here, so it may be easier for you to create a filter for "ReactNativeJS" which will only show your *console.log* messages that are created inside your React Native application.

Answer (score 1):

*console.log* can be used for any JavaScript project.

If you running the app in localhost then obviously it is similar to any JavaScript project. But while using the simulator or any device, connect that simulator to our localhost and we can see it in the console.

Answer (score 1):

There is a debugger tool in which you can see your console messages on top of your device screen. So you don't need to connect to any remote debugger that will slow down your animation or anything. You can check it here:

https://github.com/fwon/RNVConsole

Or use expo to have a try - https://snack.expo.io/SklJHMS3S

[image: Log]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this, and I am listing them and including cons in using them also.

You can use:

1. `console.log` and view logging statements on, without opting out for the remote debugging option from dev tools, Android Studio and Xcode. Or you can opt out for the remote debugging option and view logging on Google dev tools, Visual Studio Code or any other editor that supports debugging. You have to be cautious as this will slow down the process as a whole.
2. You can use `console.warn`, but then your mobile screen would be flooded with those weird yellow boxes which might or might not be feasible according to your situation.
3. The most effective method that I came across was to use a third-party tool, [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron). It is a simple-and-easy-to-configure tool that enables you to see each logging statement of different levels (error, debug, warn, etc.). It provides you with the GUI tool that shows all the logging of your application without slowing down the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the **start** script in *package.json* to

```
react-native start & react-native log-android
```

This will concurrently run both scripts

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to log.

**console.warn()** will go through the log in the mobile screen itself. It can be useful if you want to log small things and don’t want to bother opening console.

Another is **console.log()**, for which you will have to open the browser's console to view the logs. With the newer React Native 0.62+, **you can see** **the log in node itself**. So they've made it much the easier to view logs in newer version.

Comment: Re *"the log in node itself"*: Do you mean *"the log in [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)* itself? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62145010/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

If you use an iOS simulator, you can open system console log on Mac.

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, type "console", press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the system console log, and select your simulator.

Comment: What do you mean by *"open the system console log on MAC address"*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with *console.log* or the debugger available with React Native. For [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)), use [Reactotron](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron) (recommended) or [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). [Flipper](https://github.com/facebook/flipper) from Facebook is also good for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Just `console.log('debug');`.

And running it, you can see the log in the terminal/command prompt.

Comment: Explain more, and add more details.

Comment: "cd prompt" for "command prompt"? You have got to be kidding us. How cryptic can it get?

Comment: Guess Peter means to see the logs in metro server for react-native in development/debug mode. So in cmd we can do npm start and it shows all logs. This may not be applicable for install ready build packages.