# How do you debug Java code in React Native Android using console

Tags: android, react-native

JS code log can be seen on Chrome, but where do you see the log generated in the Java code?

Ok, I got the answer - using "adb logcat", but how do you debug the Java code? Is there a tool that can be used for react-native development?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: while running simulator, open android studio, then switch on the log cat monitor window or type  "adb logcat" in your terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Dave Newton, using from console via "adb logcat"

Answer (score 0):

You have a logcat in android studio as well as eclipse.

Comment: I am not using that. I'm running from console via "react-native run-android"

Comment: Your question is somewhat a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native

Comment: You may also connect your device to pc and run chrome browser and in the url type chrome://inspect