# Unable to print complete JSON using console.log

Tags: json, react-native

- I am trying to import JSON file into `Sample` variable but only first few characters are displayed from `Sample` variable.
- The sample.json is 20,00,000 characters, When i print `Sample` variable on Console only first 3,756 characters are printed.Is there any limitations on the characters that can be printed through console.log?
- Complete data persists in `Sample variable`, I verified it by searching for strings that occur at the end of `sample.json` file

  ```
  var Sample = require('./sample.json');
  export default class proj extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        locations: [],
      };
    }

    loadOnEvent() {   
        console.log(Sample);
       //this.state={ locations : Sample };
    }
  }
  ```

Is there any other way to print data in `Sample` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert json to string using `JSON.stringify` before logging.

```
/* ... */
  loadOnEvent() {   
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Sample));
     //this.state={ locations : Sample };
  }
/* ... */
```

Comment: Is it possible to be doing with parsing to String

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another way to load. Use `fetch` if file is remote or use `fs` if file is local.

If it is memory problem supposed by @Shota consider to use server side processing requests to json file. It is good solution to setup microservice which load json file at startup and handle requests to data struct parsed from json file.

---

Answer for webpack use case:

Configure webpack to use `file-loader` or `copy-webpack-plugin` for specifically this file because it enough big. Consider to load it in parallel with webpack bundle. If your application have big parts which need not each case they must be moved to [separated bundles](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

Comment: Shall i install webpack from this URL:https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webpack

Comment: I confuse tag, I just see for `webpack` tag and do not check that question have tag `react-native`. Seems you have another problem. I will remove answer. (try to use another way to load `fs` or `fetch`). If `fs` or `fetch` helpfull - please leave feedback.

Comment: Ok thanks, i tried fetch but not able to load local file using it

Comment: Please check updated question, the problem seems to be with console.log @oklas

Comment: May be console have some limitations or it is bug. Are you wabt to reveal it. Why you need to output full data? (try to output it partially) For example browser show partially data but its console is interactive and may be expanded. Pulling such big file for most cases is not good idea consider to create microservice.

Comment: I was just trying to verify whether the data was captured by printing it. However such logging statement would be commented during production release

Comment: Isn't there any other way to print data in react-native for debugging purpose?

Comment: I is another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native