# How to enable the Android monitor in React Native for checking logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am new in react native. I want to see the logs of my react files. I am using android studio for using
**react-native** project and **genny motion as a
simulator**. Can you please guide me, how can I see the logs or enable **android monitor** in android studio?

Even I have already install react dev tools from Facebook for debugging the code: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

but not able to get the particular solution

Already visit: [How do you debug React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)

[How to do logging in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native)
I have checked so many solutions but it is not working in android 6.0 versions

But not working please guide me, Thanks in Advance

Comment: if you want lighter solution you can run "react-native log-android" from your command line, but its not as fancy as debug js remotely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using window, you can try hit CTRL+M, else in mac CMD+D to open debugging menu. Once it open, choose `REMOTE JS DEBUGGING`, it will automatically open chrome browser for you to debug js error. Android studio debugging will work if you're connected on real device.

**Eg. of Debugging Menu**

[image: Debugging menu]

I've found out the answer for genYmotion from [How do you debug react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native). Don't know whether it'll work for you, but worth for try.

For an Android App, if you're using Genymotion you can toggle the menu by pressing ctrl + m, but you may have to enable it in the menu by :

- Untick **untick widget**
- click on debug in chrome

[image]

Comment: I am using linux mint so how can i open menu settings.@digit

Comment: I'm not very familiar with window and linux. You can try press ctrl+M  or alt+M on the geny simulator.

Comment: Thanks for updating but it is not working , widget is open properly but i want to open remotejs window. is it possible to open only on that case when any error has come?

Comment: Why would you. Opening remotejs window will take time and reload whole application. For me, it wasting my time for debugging. Just let it open and sorry i didn't find any resources related to the linux debugging.

Comment: its okay..Thanks for the efforts. but n clicking cltr+m or anything nothing works, i was thinking remote js debugging will work in that..

Comment: Hi from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299680/how-to-withdraw-the-bounty you cannot withdraw your bounties but you can wait for 7 day until it ending for itself. It's ok, the next 7 day you can tick my answer without having lost your point.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have resolved the issue with these above comments you can click

> **Ctrl + D and then click Ctrl + M for fetching the debugging contents**

Then Run below command for checking logs

```
React-native log-android
```

with this you will be able to see the console logs in android studio terminal log panel.

But before this you need to run command:

```
Npm start
```

for checking latest changes by fetcing bundle directly in the simulator

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple console.log command

Use Reactoron for Logging Data 
Here is the link:
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

Best thing for log in React Native.