# how to view logs for react native app in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: react-native

I made a simple sign up form using react-native from scratch.
I used **'react-native init login'**
Now to put validations I need to use console.log but I am not able to view them. I tried following some links to debugging but not able to view the logs.
I am using **Ubuntu 15.10**
Kindly help. :)

Comment: I used react-native log-android but it gets stuck on starting the logger.
react-native log-android
Scanning 647 folders for symlinks in /home/trainees10/react-native-apps/login/node_modules (11ms)
Starting the logger (adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V)...

Comment: Did you try `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` and you problem didn't solve?

Comment: i did. adb server is out of date.  killing...
cannot bind 'tcp:5037'
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error: device offline
it is showing this @VahidBoreiri

Comment: How did you install your app in your adb?

Comment: When you type `adb devices` in console is your devices listed there?

Comment: when I type adb devices it shows only one line
List of devices attached @VahidBoreiri

Comment: your device is appeared in the list like somethings like `2101109bb84fc34a 
   device`?

Comment: Problem solved. updated the adb and ran emulator and debugger side by side. now able to view. thanks @VahidBoreiri for responding :)

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is where **Chrome Developer Tools** are your friend.

The following steps should get you to the Chrome Developer Tools, where you will be able to see your `console.log` statements.

### Steps

1. Install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html), if you have not already
2. Run app using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`
3. Open developer menu

   - Mac: `⌘+D`  for iOS or `⌘M` for Android iOS
   - Windows/Linux: Shake Android phone
4. Select `Debug JS Remotely`
5. This should launch the debugger in Chrome
6. In Chrome: `Tools -> More Tools -> Developer Options` and make sure you are on the `console` tab

Now whenever a `console.log` statement is executed, it should appear in Chrome Dev Tools. The official documentation is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native/38099445#38099445) (which at the time of this answer is two years old and only for iOS).

Comment: This is an alternative to running `react-native log-android` to see your logs