# How can I print state in the console with React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to print the state in the console for debugging, but I get this error message:

> **Cannot read property 'petname' of undefined**

What is the right way to print state in the console and why is this calling it a property?

```js
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      petname: '',
      owner: ''
    };
  }

  addPet() {
    console.log("Button Pressed");
    console.log(this.state.petname);
    return (
      //some logic
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inputStyle}>
          <Text>Pet</Text>
          <TextInput onChangeText={petname =>                                 this.setState({petname})} style={{width:100}} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputStyle} >
          <Button title="Add Pet" onPress={this.addPet} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is not accessible in your function. Either you can bind `this` with your function on `onPress` or you can write the following in your constructor.

```javascript
this.addPet = this.addPet.bind(this);
```

Comparing the first and second option, the second option is better, because it doesn't create a new instance every time.

The best option is to use the arrow function (an [ES6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2015) feature). Consider the following example.

```javascript
addPet = () => {
  // Your awesome logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Working but I more question Why should we bind addPet function? What is the motive behind this?

Comment: binding this is ES5 solution, now we have arrow functions (ES6). You can read discussion [here about this topic](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/513)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```html
<Button title="Add Pet" onPress={this.addPet.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the function to this:

```javascript
addPet = () => {
    console.log("Button Pressed");
    console.log(this.state.petname);
    return (
        // Some logic
    );
}
```