# react native data show on console.log but not on screen

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Sometimes the app working well.
but I dont know why, sometimes the data from firebase give me blank screen instead of the data.
after I reopen the app it work.

for example,
one of my pages:

```
useEffect( () => {
        const subscriber =  firestore()
          .collection('Trails')
          .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => { //const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').get();
            const trails = [];
            console.log('subscribe')
            if (querySnapshot)
              querySnapshot.forEach(async documentSnapshot => {
                trails.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  key: documentSnapshot.id,

                });
                console.log("trails test", trails)
                
              });

            
            setTrails(trails);
            setLoading(false);
          });
        return () => {subscriber()};
      }, []);
```

I made useEffect to get the data from DB then show it, and same - sometimes give me blank and sometimes works well.

I want to publish the app but im not satisfying with this bug?

sorry for my English, I dont even know how to describe this problem better.

Please can anyone guide me through? maybe my useEffect not doing well?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use debugging.

[React native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging)

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115372/how-to-do-logging-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's issue with the return in useEffect return is called when componeent unmounts. here's an example how i handle async data fetching:

```
...
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const isCurrentView = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isCurrentView.current === true) {

    const asyncFetch = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(...something) //here some Asynchronous Call Like(axios, fetch)
      setData([...response]);
    };

    asyncFetch();
  }

  return () => {
    isCurrentView.current = false;
  };
}, []);
...
```

im not 100% sure if this is the VERY best approach, but i have seen similar code in places so i addopted this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this,
The problem also occurs also with markers but once user restart the app it works :<

Comment: it fetch, appears and then dissappear (as I did the  asyncFetch() twice?)

Answer (score 0):

problem was solved:
the setTrails was under scope and it kept refreshing with empty data.

```
querySnapshot.forEach(async documentSnapshot => {
                trails.push({
                  ...documentSnapshot.data(),
                  key: documentSnapshot.id,

                });
              setTrails(trails);  // <<<~~~~ put the set in this scope.
            });
              setLoading(false);
          });
```